# Class not register while opening outlook in 64 bit system

Tags: outlook, 64-bit

While running our windows application on 64 bit system , we are facing some issue for opening outlook . It says "Class not registered" error  . We tried to register the outlook dll and again it is showing error like entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found . Make sure that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll is a valid dll or OCX file and then try again .We are using below commands for registering the dlls ..

C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe /i Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe /i Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll

FYI , our windows application -> target platform is set to 'Any CPU' for Build

Appreciate the help , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the Outlook bitness? Is it 32 bit?
The bitness of your app must match the bitness of Outlook, not the parent OS (which is what "Any CPU" does).
Also keep in mind that your interop dll is just a binary header, it is not the real COM object (which in case of Outlook is implemented by outlookj.exe).

Comment: its 2010 outlook , 32 bit ... and this issue is coming only in citrix with 64 bit

Comment: So are you compiling your app as "Any CPU"? You should use x86 if you want to target 32 bit Outlook.